# How to setup multiple environments (Development, Staging and Production) from Android Studio Firebase Assistance in a single Firebase projects

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, production

Currently, I am working on an android project which has multiple subprojects. The project is connected to firebase through Android Studio Firebase Assistance tools. I need to setup multiple environments (Development, Staging, and Production).

I have created multiple projects for each environment in firebase but am not able to change or connect to other firebase projects through Android Studio Firebase Assistance tools.

Is this the correct way? I need suggestions to solve this issue.

Comment: I normally do this manually by copying the google-services.json file to the respective locations.

Comment: i am also doing the same. i am looking for something better way.